# Node Inspector only loads the www file when preload is set to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

When I run

```
node-inspector
```

My node-inspector browser window loads all the files correctly.

[image: All files loaded correctly]

When I run

```
node-inspector --preload=false
```

My node-inspector window only loads my bin/www file.

[image: All files missing except the www]

My colleagues are loading node-inspector the same way, but not experiencing the same problem. When they load it with `preload=false` they are able to see all the files.

Have I not configured something correctly? I've tried re-installing node-inspector, node. I'm thinking about doing the same with Chrome next. Waiting for the files to preload is very inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled node, reinstalled it to the latest version (4.2.6) and node-inspector started working again appropriately.